# How to sort by key AND value in SICStus Prolog?

Tags: sorting, prolog

I have a list like

```
L = [0-4, 0-3, 3-5, 1-2]
```

and I would like to sort the list by key and value so the result would be

```
L = [0-3, 0-4, 1-2, 3-5]
```

I found [keysort](http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.2.3/html/sicstus/mpg_002dref_002dkeysort.html) but it sorts only by key. I can write the sort by myself but I need an efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call sort/2 (or msort/2 if you want keep duplicates)

```
?- sort([0-4, 0-3, 3-5, 1-2], S).
S = [0-3, 0-4, 1-2, 3-5].
```